# Who is on the Australian Health Protection Principal Committee?

Tags: australia, public-health

During this covid-19 event, Australians have been addressed by the Prime Minister Scott Morrison a number of times, where he has delivered speeches and informed the public of what actions are appropriate to take, and what the government is doing about the situation. A number of times, he tells us that he is being advised by the Australian Health Protection Principal Committee.

Here is a webpage describing the AHPPC: https://www.health.gov.au/committees-and-groups/australian-health-protection-principal-committee-ahppc

> The Australian Health Protection Principal Committee is the key decision making committee for health emergencies. It is comprised of all state and territory Chief Health Officers and is chaired by the Australian Chief Medical Officer.

The Chief Medical Officer is [Brendan Murphy](https://www.health.gov.au/contacts/chief-medical-officer).

For the other members of the committee, we are left with this:

> Contacts for the Chief Health Officers can be found on each state and territory's websites.

I have tried to find the name of the person who is the Chief Health Officer for each state, and have been able to find a few, but most I couldn't find.

Who are these Chief Health Officers?

(The only two I could find are [Brad Hazzard](https://www.health.nsw.gov.au/ministers/Pages/default.aspx) for New South Wales and [Jenny Mikakos](https://www.dhhs.vic.gov.au/our-ministers) for Victoria)

Comment: Hazzard and Mikakos are not the Chief Health Officers, they are the Health Ministers. Dr Kerry Chant is the CHO for NSW, but I'm not sure where to find a full list.

Comment: @CDJB oh! my bad. Even better reason for me to have posted this question...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are the Chief Health Officers (CHO) I could find:

- [Victoria](https://twitter.com/VictorianCHO) - Prof Brett Sutton
- [New South Wales](https://www.health.nsw.gov.au/about/ministry/Pages/chart.aspx) - Dr. Kery Chant
- [Queensland](https://www.abc.net.au/news/2020-03-27/queensland-chief-health-officer-dr-jeannette-young,-with-health/12097778) - Dr. Jeannette Young
- [Tasmania](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/52378/29681) - As it turns out, [Tasmania has a slightly different title that serves the same function](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/52378/29681). Dr. Mark Veitch does everything a CHO would do. See my link for more information.
- [Western Australia](https://ww2.health.wa.gov.au/About-us/Department-of-Health/Public-Health) - Dr. Andrew Robertson
- [South Australia](https://www.sahealth.sa.gov.au/wps/wcm/connect/public+content/sa+health+internet/about+us/about+sa+health/our+chief+officers/chief+medical+officer+and+chief+public+health+officer) - Professor Paddy Phillips.
- [Northern Territory](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2020/mar/17/how-australia-will-enforce-coronavirus-self-isolation-rules-for-overseas-arrivals) - (Acting) Di Stevens
- [Australian Capital Territory (ACT)](https://health.act.gov.au/about-our-health-system/population-health) -  Dr Kerryn Coleman