# Why did Secretary Michael Pervan not appoint a CHO in 2018?

Tags: healthcare, australia, public-health

So, [I was looking at the Australian Chief Health Officers](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/52344/who-is-on-the-australian-health-protection-principal-committee) (CHOs), and couldn't find one for Tasmania.

Upon further investigation, it looks like [the Tasmanian Health Department was re-organized in 2018](https://tasmaniantimes.com/2018/06/welcome-to-our-new-department-of-health/):

> As you will be aware, the new Tasmanian Health Service Act 2018 also comes in to effect on 1 July 2018 which means that the Tasmanian Health Service also now reports directly me as Secretary, Department of Health.

Absent from this list seems to be a CHO. Why is that? Did the Tasmanian Health Service Act 2018 make it obsolete?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

He did.  Only the title is slightly different 
Under the Public Health Act 1997, Tasmania doesn’t have a CHO.  We have a Director of Public Health Services which has all the powers of a CHO. That is Dr Mark Veitch

In addition I appointed Professor Tony Laaler to a new position of Chief Medical Officer.

Comment: "In addition I appointed," Wait, are you Michael, as in Michael Pervan?

Comment: You can [edit] your question by hitting the edit button just below the body of the answer. On StackExchange sites, people are expected to edit their answer to improve it, rather than posting new answers. Also, while you don't yet have the 50 rep needed to [comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19757/388335), I believe you're still able to comment on your own questions and answers to reply to people.